# How to make Checkbutton which is automatically checked using gtk

Tags: python, gtk

I need to make checkbutton using gtk and python. Idea is that check button is automatically checked (not by user) if some asked condition was satisfied. For example: If I write in entry number 7, then the button would be checked, otherwise it would be unchecked.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is. Changing the check state of the check button is easy, as [`GtkCheckButton` is a subclass of `GtkToggleButton`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/GtkToggleButton.html#gtk-toggle-button-set-active):

```
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(btn), state);
```

Or in Python:

```
btn.set_active(state)
```

More interesting is when to call this function. If your check condition is only the contents of an entry control, just bind a function to the signal [`changed`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/GtkEditable.html#GtkEditable-changed) of that control. However, if there are many things that can make the condition change, you can consider writing an [idle](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) function, and check it there.